# html password regular expression validation

Tags: html, regex

I need to validate password with these requirements:-

- At least 1 Uppercase
- At least 1 Lowercase
- At least 1 Number
- At least 1 Symbol, symbol allowed --> !@#$%^&*_=+-
- Min 8 chars and Max 12 chars

And got stucked a bit, here's what I have so far.

```
<form>
Password <input type="text" pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*_=+-]{8,12}$/g" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcLcn9va/1/)

Comment: I hope you’re not using that for anything in the real world? Those password requirements are pretty silly. Anyways, don’t use delimiters; remove the `/` at the beginning of the pattern and the `/g` at the end.

Comment: It's for my company internal use only.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try this pattern

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{8,12}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/171)

Comment: Nice use of lookahead!

Comment: Thanks! am not very good in regex and thanks for sharing such awesome website as well.